# NullPointerException while getting font from my JButton

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jbutton

I wanted to create button which would auto resize while the `string` inside of it cannot be displayed (it is too big).

I got something like that:

```
public class ResizingButton extends JButton {
    public ResizingButton(String txt) {
        super(txt);
        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                setText(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Text"));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String arg0) {
        super.setText(arg0);
        FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(getFont());//nullPointerException !!!
        int width = metrics.stringWidth(getText());
        int height = metrics.getHeight();
        Dimension newDimension = new Dimension(width + 40, height + 10);
        setPreferredSize(newDimension);
        setBounds(new Rectangle(getLocation(), getPreferredSize()));
    }
}
```

I wanted to use that class:

```
public class Zadanie2 extends JFrame {
    public Zadanie2() {
        createGUI();
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        setSize(200, 80);
        //setLayout(new GridLayout());
        add(new ResizingButton("tekst"));
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Zadanie2();
    }
}
```

But I am getting null pointer exception in `setText()` method? Why is that happening, and how can I repair it? **`getFont()` returns null and then `getFontMetrics(null)` throws exception.**

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.hash(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.get(Unknown Source)
    at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(Unknown Source)
    at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(Unknown Source)
    at ResizingButton.setText(ResizingButton.java:26)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JButton.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JButton.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at ResizingButton.<init>(ResizingButton.java:13)
    at Zadanie2.createGUI(Zadanie2.java:14)
    at Zadanie2.<init>(Zadanie2.java:8)
    at Zadanie2.main(Zadanie2.java:20)
```

Comment: Running your code, I see a NullPointerException in getFontMetrics(), not in getFont(). Can you please post the exception stack trace?

Comment: @CyrilleKa You are right `getFont()` returns null and then `getFontMetrics(null)` throws exception

Comment: I think it is probably related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014135/why-am-i-getting-this-nullpointerexception As long as the JButton is not "displayed" (attached to your JFrame), some graphics-related methods will not work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long story short:
Change `super(txt)` to

```
super();
setText(txt);
```

***Short explanation***
As the stack-trace indicates, calling `super(txt)` (with a String argument) calls at some point `AbstractButton`'s `init` method:

```
protected void init(String text, Icon icon) {
    if (text != null) {
        setText(text);
    }
    ...
```

As you can see, **IF** the `text` argument is not `null`, method `setText` is called. But your overriden `setText` method requires the Font to be set (which at this point isn't).

So, calling the no-argument constructor first (`super()`), causes the `text` argument passed to `init` to be `null`, thus avoiding the problem. Only **after** `super()` returns (at which point the Font has been properly set), is it safe to call `setText(txt)` explicitely and everything works fine.

(Long story short **plus** happy ending !)

Comment: Right, that's a cleverer solution than my answer.

Comment: I got the long story : ). I meant short version was clear enough. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `setText()` is called from `JButton`'s constructor, apparently before the `font` field is initialized. This is bad coding practice on the part of the Swing folks, but you can work around it by just doing nothing if `getFont() == null`.